# Deploy Spring Batch to AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, spring-batch

I am new to AWS. I have developed a batch processing application using Spring boot, batch and Quartz for scheduling. It pulls a file from remote FTP server and loads into DB. Can someone pls help, how can I deploy this to AWS?

Will this be on Elastic Beanstalk (EC2) instance with volume mounted to it for downloading the file from FTP and then processing?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You should probably look at the official Spring site, [Spring Cloud AWS](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-aws/spring-cloud-aws.html). It is a somewhat involved process, but powerful. If your job is a small one, you may wish to consider a AWS Lambda function instead.